# Error in SQL Syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a query to delete a raw in a database. This is the query:

```
"delete from ombrellone where PosizioneX='"+i+"'AND PosizioneY='"+j+"')");
```

I don't know what I wrong. Anyone can help me?

The exception is:

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
```

Comment: I think the error is obvious . . . you have a closing paren but no opening paren.  In the future, print out your SQL statements after variable substitution.  Maybe you can see the error yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"delete from ombrellone where PosizioneX='" + i + "' AND PosizioneY = '" + j +"'";
```